# Idiom/expression that means "canceling" an event from your calendar?

Tags: expressions, idioms

This is a bit tricky because *checking off* and *crossing out* could mean that I marked those items as finished. What I want to convey is that I changed my mind and decided not to do those items.

Example:

> My calendar was empty, since I'd already [...] "Going to Hawaii" from
>   it.

Comment: You "remove" events from a diary don't you?

Comment: Probably ***postponed*** suggests the idea of not having dealt with them yet, but simply moved to a future date.

Comment: Not much different, but I cross things **off**.

Comment: I think "cancelling" an event (**in** my calendar) pretty much covers it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, check off = mark an item as *finished or done*

Cross out = *remove or cancel the item*

I think, in your case, it'd be "cross out".

Answer (score 4):

The word *[erased](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/erase)* conveys the metaphoric meaning:

> ***removed*** from my schedule.

When someone asks me to schedule a meeting or event, I often say, "I can *pencil you in*, but we'll need to confirm details before I schedule this." I don't actually use a pencil, but the imagery of using a pencil implies that it will be easy for me to eliminate the entry from my computer if the details don't confirm.

> *My calendar was empty, since I'd already **erased** "Going to Hawaii" from it.*

Answer (score 3):

You can **axe** your planned trip to Hawaii, which means to cancel or end suddenly.

For example, if you have too many activities or responsibilities to take care of, some of them, such as your vacation plans, may have to **get the axe**.

This is an informal metaphor, and not an expression you would use in a professional or formal statement.

You can **scrub** your plans, which means to cancel or postpone them. Also informal.

**Call off** means to cancel, and can be used both informally and formally.

In less delicate company, you can say your vacation plans had to be **shitcanned** for whatever reason. This might convey your great disappointment about the fact. *Shitcan* can also mean *fire* from a job. It can be use to mean disposing of something (that was expected to have some value).

Comment: So, it's common to say, "I axed "Going to London" from my schedule?" (In everyday conversation or literature.)

Comment: Yes, you can say that. Or "I axed my trip to London." "I scrubbed my plan to go to London." "My London trip has been called off." Or "With all this work we have, our weekend in London will have to be shitcanned."

Comment: Scrubbed suits the bill here as it works for both the event and the plan to attend an event (e.g. "the festival was scrubbed" vs. "I scrubbed my plans to go to the festival").

Comment: I definitely think that 'axed' would be the correct term, at least in British English.

Answer (score 2):

In our brave new world of electronic devices, the word *[deleted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/delete)* seems like a good candidate:

> *My calendar was empty, since I'd already **deleted** "Going to Hawaii" from it.*

Answer (score 0):

*Blot out* might work, a blot being a stain of ink, so it conveys the image of the writing being blackened over by a cloud of ink, which is more emphatic than the image of it being crossed out.